# Entity Framework type conversion issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this entity:

```
public class ResourceConfigPool
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public bool TabOrder { get; set; }
}
```

SQL Server table:

Column `TABORDER char(1)`

Request:

```
var tabOrder = _uow.Repository<ResourceConfigPool>().Get()
                    .Where(cf => cf.ResourceId == id)
                    .Select(cf => cf.TabOrder)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

And I get this error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid

**Question:** how can I resolve this issue?

PS: I can't change the SQL Server side

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you trying to map a `char` in the db to a `bool` in your model? Isn't you're model wrong? I thought the error message was pretty clear on that...

Comment: If TABORDER is a *char(1)*, it maps to a string. You *can't* map it to a bool. What would the letter `Z` translate to? If you want to convert some character values to a bool ad a transformation in your code or even a read-only property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't change anything from SQL server side, you can try to create another property that will convert the value of the string. Example:

```
public class ResourceConfigPool
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string TabOrder { get; set; }
    public bool TabOrderBool 
    { 
        get { return TabOrder == "1"; } // or "Y"
    }
}
```

then query query from the newly added property:

```
var tabOrder = _uow.Repository<ResourceConfigPool>().Get()
                    .Where(cf => cf.ResourceId == id)
                    .Select(cf => cf.TabOrderBool)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Sorry for the overbearing, your answer is perfect, but maybe Is it possible to convert types using EntityTypeConfiguration<ResourceConfigPool>, or create own Fluetn operator operator???